# Handling categorical missing values ML

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, missing-data, data-imputation

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46120727/replace-missing-values-in-categorical-data) regarding handling missing values in categorical data.

Dataset has about `6 categorical columns` with `missing values`. This would be for a binary classification problem

I see different approaches where one is to `just leave the missing values in category column as such`, other to impute using `from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer`, but unsure which is better option.

In case if `imputing` is better option, which libraries could I use before applying the model like `LR,Decision Tree, RandomForest`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would look how many missing values there are in the column. If there are too much (~20%, generally its difficult to say how much is too much), I would drop the column because imputing 20 % of your data (without prior expert knowledge) or even more probably does not give you meaningful information anymore.

Secondly I would look at correlations between missing values and other features. Maybe you are lucky and there is some correlation between missing values in column x and a categorical value in column y. Simply look at conditional distributions.

If you choose to impute, check the distribution of the categorical values for non-missing entries. If the distribution is heavily skewed, say there is 95% value 0 and only 5% value 1, you can use the median to impute. Again, the question is how informative this is in the end. Otherwise create an additional categorical value which simply represents a missing value.

Comment: Don't you think 20% is way to less to drop the feature?? I have been imputing features with 50% nan values.

Answer (score 1):

The first question we must ask is **“why are these values missing?”**

1. **Skip** the feature if it's > 25%
2. Try to **know the reason** from the data source/provider. They might give a clue and you may use that e.g. One city has Power failure during data collection.
3. Simply **create a new category** for the missing and check the result. This will only work when there is an underlying reason for missing
4. Try Calculating/Guessing on domain knowledge the **correlation with other Feature** and then fill with respective values. I am making this point to avoid mean/median on full columns e.g. In below data, Mean on full column ~750 but we should fill with ~100

[image]

4. **K Nearest Neighbour** - This can do both the steps of #3 in one go. Fortunately, SciKitLearn has an Imputer. *e.g. [sklearn.impute.KNNImputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.KNNImputer.html) (Keep one categorical at a time)*
5. **Blind approach** - Simply replace with Mean/Median. For categorical - most_frequent (Mode)
   `SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent")`
6. **Try a few** and monitor the result to decide the best approach
7. A thoughtful read - 

   [Max Kuhn and Kjell Johnson](http://www.feat.engineering/imputation-methods.html)

   > *One point that I wanted to make is to look into the data as an event/cause-effect and try to figure out things before directly looking for hammer/guns esp. if its a real project. It's ok if it is learning stuff.*

Comment: 25% is way too less to drop the feature. I have imputed features with 50% nan values.

Answer (score 0):

How about training a ML classification model where all the features are used as an input and label is your categorical values. In that way we can predict the missing value.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to the other answers that columns might be useful even if they contain more than half of missing values *if those missing values carry meaning*. For example, in  credit risk modeling, there might be a column with some financial statement indicator where a missing value might mean that the person refused to provide the financial statement, itself a big red flag for risk. Therefore, it is always helpful to clarify this with wherever the data came from.